# How to calculate the sum of periods over each column for each row and divide it by a total minimum value in R

Tags: r

I have a calculation where I accumulate the sum of each flower in the table below for each year. However, I would like to use the same calculation to also divide the accumulated values by a total minimum value.

(Data Frame)

```
 dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  flower = c("lily", "rose", "daisy"),
  x1902 = c(23L, 50L, 30L),
  x1950 = c(23L, 110L, 37L),
  x2010 = c( 23L, 115L, 47L),
  x2012 = c( 31L, 131L, 49L),
  x2021 = c( 36L, 131L, 49L),
  total_min = c(5L, 5L, 2L)
```

The code that I used to do the accumulation as follows:

```
dat[, 2:6] <- t(apply(dat[,2:6], 1, cumsum))
```

So now I need to divide the accumulated amount by the total min for each flower type for each year. I tried the code as follows but I am not getting the correct results:

```
dat[,2:6] <- t(apply(dat[,2:6], 1, cumsum)/dat$total_min)
```

(Table 1 - DataFrame)

| flower | x1902 | x1950 | x2010 | x2012 | x2021 | total_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lily | 23 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 5 | 5 |
| rose | 50 | 60 | 5 | 16 | 0 | 5 |
| daisy | 30 | 7 | 10 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Calculating the sum for each flower in each year. The end result gives me:

(Table 2 - Accumulated results )

| flower | x1902 | x1950 | x2010 | x2012 | x2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lily | 23 | 23 | 23 | 31 | 36 |
| rose | 50 | 110 | 115 | 131 | 131 |
| daisy | 30 | 37 | 47 | 49 | 49 |

The final result should look like Table 3

(Table 3 - expected results)

| flower | x1902 | x1950 | x2010 | x2012 | x2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lily | 4.6 | 4.6 | 4.6 | 6.2 | 7.2 |
| rose | 10 | 22 | 23 | 26.2 | 26.2 |
| daisy | 15 | 18.5 | 23.5 | 24.5 | 24.5 |

Comment: Your expected result will get by using `dat[,2:6] <- dat[,2:6] / dat$total_min`.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with the code in the question are:

- the final ) is in the wrong place
- although not wrong it would be less error prone to create a new version of the data with a different name.
- also it would be a bit more robust if we extract the columns whose names start with `x` rather than hard coding 2:6.

**1)** Using `dat0` shown in the Note at the end we have:

```
xnms <- startsWith(names(dat0), "x")
dat2 <- replace(dat0, xnms, t(apply(dat0[xnms], 1, cumsum)) / dat0$total_min)
dat2
##   flower x1902 x1950 x2010 x2012 x2021 total_min
## 1   lily   4.6   4.6   4.6   6.2   7.2         5
## 2   rose  10.0  22.0  23.0  26.2  26.2         5
## 3  daisy  15.0  18.5  23.5  24.5  24.5         2
```

**2)** Another approach is `Reduce`:

```
replace(dat0, xnms, 
  as.data.frame(Reduce("+", dat0[xnms], acc = TRUE)) / dat0$total_min)
```

### Note

```
dat0 <-
structure(list(flower = c("lily", "rose", "daisy"), x1902 = c(23L, 
50L, 30L), x1950 = c(0L, 60L, 7L), x2010 = c(0L, 5L, 10L), x2012 = c(8L, 
16L, 2L), x2021 = c(5L, 0L, 0L), total_min = c(5L, 5L, 2L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

dat0
##   flower x1902 x1950 x2010 x2012 x2021 total_min
## 1   lily    23     0     0     8     5         5
## 2   rose    50    60     5    16     0         5
## 3  daisy    30     7    10     2     0         2
```